# Can I run auth flows in browser address bar or curl?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I've used ADAL in many applications to implement variety of auth flows.

ADAL shileds me againest knowing what is behind the sceene. I like to go byond the [oauth2 sequence diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types). I know people can test/experiment oauth2 flows by using CURL, Postman or even browser address bar.

Is there any demo or learning resource that shows how to run auth flows outside the ADAL library?

Comment: Of course you can, like you mention in the question itself, using ADAL libraries isn't mandatory, you do it using CURL, Postman or even browser directly (anyway you can reach the relevant authorization/token endpoints with correct information/protocol).. Here is an example of Client Credentials grant flow used to call Azure REST API via curl.. https://medium.com/@mauridb/calling-azure-rest-api-via-curl-eb10a06127 I am not sure if you were interested in a particular flow, so not posting it as answer..

Comment: Take a look at this direct Microsoft Docs explanation of OAuth 2.0 Authorization code grant flow.. Since all the GET/POST calls made to endpoints as well as respective responses are clearly shown, you should be able to follow clearly how things flow or even try similar HTTP requests yourself.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: Agreeing with all the comments and answer(s) here from Rohit and Tom. On a side note, wouldn't it be more appropriate to remove the `ADAL` tag in this question, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any demo or learning resource that shows how to run auth flows outside the ADAL library?

Yes, but before do that, I recommend that you could refer to azure official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code) to learn what is [OpenID](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) Connect protocol and OAuth 2.0.

Then we could know the kind of flows of OAuth 2.0 such as [implicit grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow), [auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code), [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) and [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

The articles also have the detail steps mentioned how to implement variety of auth flows.

Rohit Saigal also mentioned how to use the Azure Rest API via CURL.

This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-z6FM02D0WA) is the demo about how to use the postman to get the access token.